# Fantasy book series with non-human races and labyrinth

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to identify fantasy book series I encountered some time ago. Here are things I remember:

- it was a fantasy setting but with some s-f elements; with many worlds and possibility to travel between them; resembling [Planescape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planescape) setting a little,
- the two main races were non-human and probably hostile to each other,
- a labyrinth (?), which somehow played an important role in the plot,
- a protagonist was some kind of emissary and was sent on a mission to another worlds
- time period: 80s - 90s

Does anyone know what it is the name of the series?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Death Gate Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_Gate_Cycle) is a series of seven fantasy novels by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman that involves planar travel and contains quite a few sci-elements. The books were released between 1990 and 1994.

The series features:

- Travel between multiple elemental planes of existence: the Plane of Fire, Plane of Earth, Plane of Air, Plane of Water.
- The the Sartan and the Patryns, two godlike races, are locked in a war to control the other, "lesser" races (Dwarves, elves and humans).
- The Labyrinth is a prison world that figures largely into the Sartan/Patryn conflict. Spoiler alert:

  > The Patryn are imprisoned there.
- One of the main characters is Haplo, a agent of the Patryn who travels among the Elemental worlds at his master's request.

Comment: This is it! Thanks, @Discord.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly some of the books in the [Riftwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Riftwar_Cycle) cycle by Raymond Feist?

- multiple worlds with different ways of access through portals
- Non-human races - Elves, serpent people, Valheru. At the beginning of the series the main race is human, but many of the major characters are not human.
- Pug (aka Milamber), the main character of most of the original books, travels back and forth to many of these worlds in various roles, from slave to emissary to ambassador.
- Some parts of the stories take place in caves and labyrinth-like "between worlds" places
- the series ran from 1982 to at least 2000.

Comment: An interesting cycle, but unfortunately that's not it.